# How to Handle Errors in WKWebView in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

When you access a website without internet, does the browser return a certain error page? in my `WKWebView`, which intercepted this error?

Comment: I think you are looking for `didFail` event: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        let error = error as NSError
        print(error.code)
        switch(error.code){
        case NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet:
            //some code
            break
        case NSURLErrorTimedOut:
            //some code
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```